# Strange join syntax in legacy SQL code

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I have some legacy code I'm going through, and i just found a join with two "on" clauses...

```
select * from table
inner join table3
inner join table2 on table3.key = table2.fkey on table.key = table2.otherkey
```

What does this kind of join mean? (It currently works so it's not a syntax error)

(Edit: Fixed the code, was missing a join)

Comment: Are you sure? I can't get such a statement to compile

Comment: Sorry, missed a join crucial to the strange join :) Edited original post...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Post your edit it's just a case of knowing the implicit precedence.

```
select * from table1
inner join table3
inner join table2 on table3.key = table2.fkey on table1.key = table2.otherkey
```

is the same as

```
select * from 
table1 inner join 
   (table3 inner join table2 on table3.key = table2.fkey)
on table1.key = table2.otherkey
```

which hopefully makes more sense. All I have done here is add parentheses.

The first join, `table3` to `table2`, conceptually speaking produces an intermediate table with all the columns from both. `table1` is then joined to this using the second `on` clause you see.

Comment: Ah, yes... That makes sense, but makes for awful to read code :|